# Errors with config/routes.rb after uninstalling Zurb Foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, config

Tried uninstalling Zurb Foundation from my Rails app using "gem uninstall foundation-rails", and despite a message saying the gem was uninstalled successfully, I occassionally get the following error message on my page:

cannot load such file -- /Users/blahblahblah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/foundation-rails-5.1.1.0/config/routes.rb

I don't see anything referencing the Foundation file in routes.rb, where should I be looking?

Comment: Are you using bundler? Have you removed the foundation rails gem from your gemfile and run `bundle install`?

Comment: Yep, done that. The error message is infrequent/inconsistent, i.e. only maybe once ever 10 or so times I visit the page.

Comment: I would check in your application's initializers. Perhaps somewhere in an initializer in `config/` or `config/environments` your app is looking for Foundation

Comment: Can't find anything there, but error messages aren't popping up any more, no clue what was going on...